# Sending mails from spreadsheet with new rows: Problem with cells with formulas

Tags: google-apps-script

I've a script to send a mail if a new row is added to a spreadsheet. I want to send the mail to a address in the new row which is fetched by a function (=vlookup(...)), but this pre-filled function is regarded also as a new row. How can I avoid this?

I think the special columns with the function must be excluded in the process, but I don't know how ...

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('xxx')
  var StartRow = 3;
  var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
  var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,33);//Added a new column for recipient email address
  var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<AllValues.length;i++) {
    var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
    var Subject = "Neu: " + CurrentRow[7] + " für Ressort " + CurrentRow[5]  + " - "+ CurrentRow[6];
    var message = "<p><b>Ressort: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Textart: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Domain: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Thema: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" + "<p><b>fertig bis: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>";
    var EmailSent = CurrentRow[0];
    var SendTo = (CurrentRow[32])?CurrentRow[32]:"aaa@bbb.com" + "," + "xxx@yyy.com";//conditional (ternary) operator.  If CurrentRow[32] is there then use it otherwise use your default.
    if (EmailSent != "gesendet") {
      var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;
      ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 1).setValue("gesendet");
      MailApp.sendEmail({to: SendTo,cc: "",subject: Subject,htmlBody: message});
    }
  }
}
```

The cells with the function should not be included in the WholeRange but RowRange seems not to work.

Comment: There are numerous ways to solve this problem depending on your needs, sheet contents, and how you are triggering your script. For instance, consider removing the `var SendTo` line and move it to `if (Email Sent !== "gesendet" && CurrentRow[32]) { var SendTo = CurrentRow[32]; ...`

Comment: Can you share an example of the table you are using to send the data?

Comment: here's an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cZcLDjXA48_wmFJj8vh9HBJ3Fz5HQWFPkdJOlooNj_I/edit#gid=1094014592

Comment: any ideas on this?

Comment: Because there's no reaction so far, I like to try another way: I like to add another condition to " `if (EmailSent != "gesendet")`. The `setValue("gesendet")`should only work if the're one or more correct formatted mailadresses in a special cell in the current row. If there's NOT at least one mail address the script should do nothing.